# In a DVR, why does $u=f(t,u)$, with $f$ a homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$ and $t$ a uniformizer, imply $\nu(u)=3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-curves, valuation-theory

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/660534) by Georges Elencwajg, it is stated that

> $$u=t^3-\dots-e_1e_2e_3u^3=\text{a homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$ in t,u}\quad(\ast)$$
>   [...]
>
> Now in the local ring $\mathcal O_{C,P}$, a discrete valuation ring, equation $(\ast)$ implies that $u$ has valuation $3$.

In that context, $C$ is an algebraic curve and $t$ is a uniformizer for $\mathcal O_{C,P}$.

Why does this implication hold?

Comment: The equation allows you to write $t^3(1+\alpha) = u$ where $\alpha \in (t,u)$, so $1+\alpha$ is a unit in the local ring.

Comment: @Hoot Ah, that's really simple. I was quite close; I had only neglected to notice that $1+\alpha$ was invertible. Thank you!